# Exercise-differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If the graph of the solution u of the differential equation $y''-4y'+29y=0$ intersects the graph of the solution v of the differential equation $y''+4y'+13y=0$ at the point (0,0),how can I find u,v so that:

$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{v^{4}(x)}{u(x)}=\frac{5}{6} $ ?

Comment: Find solutions of both equations (you will have 2 arbitrary constants in each of them), use the fact that both of the pass through the point $(0,0)$ (therefore only one arbitrary constant in each solution),, then use the limiting behaviour.

Comment: I found that the solution of this differential equation $y''-4y'+29y=0$ is $y(x)=c_{1}e^{2x}sin(5x)+c_{2}e^{2x}cos(5x)$.We know that $y(0)=0$,so $c_{2}=0$, and $y(x)=c_{1}e^{2x}sin(5x)$.
I also found that the solution of the differential equation  $y''+4y'+13y=0$ is $y(x)=d_{1}e^{-2x}sin(3x)+d_{2}e^{-2x}cos(3x),$y(0)=0$, so $d_{2}=0 $ and $y(x)=d_{1}e^{-2x}sin(3x)$ . Is this right so far?And how can I continue?

Comment: So far everything seems correct. Now you can use the conditions on the limit: $\frac{v^4}{u} = \frac{d_1^4}{c_1}\frac{e^{-8x}\sin ^4(3x)}{e^{2x}\sin (5x)}\to \frac{5}{6}$. Clearly, even if the limit exists (which I doubt), it would be zero. Therefore, the whole problem has no solutions.

Comment: And if $x->0$ ,would the problem have solutions??

Comment: Nope, because the expression I wrote goes to zero as $x\to 0$ (because of sinuses). By the way, you can use `\to` to obtain the arrow $\to$.

Comment: The exercise I am looking at asks me to find u and v so that : $ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{v^{4}(x)}{u(x)}=\frac{5}{6} $ 
Is the right answer that there are no u,v that satisfy this condition?